# How to traverse Subversion repository to find specific file, and stop searching further down?

Tags: perl, svn, list, repository, traversal

I have this problem: given a Subversion repository `http://svn/trunk/` I want to search the whole repository to find/list all files named `exp.xml` (their whole URL). Once the first occurence has been found I want it to **stop searching further** down the URL. Just to make it clear, here are some fictitious URLs:

```
http://svn/trunk/pro1/sub-pro-x/exp.xml/sub-pro-x1/exp.xml
http://svn/trunk/pro2/sub-pro-y/pro-y1/exp.xml/sub-pro-y1/exp.xml
http://svn/trunk/pro3/sub-pro-z/exp.xml/sub-pro-z1/exp.xml/sub-proj/exp.xml
```

The **result** should be:

```
http://svn/trunk/pro1/sub-pro-x/exp.xml
http://svn/trunk/pro2/sub-pro-y/pro-y1/exp.xml
http://svn/trunk/pro3/sub-pro-z/exp.xml
```

Now I already have a solution, but it's not really very efficient because I use `grep exp.xml` after `svn -R list ---` has searched the whole repository (30-40 min). In case you want to know, here is the command:

```
svn list -R http://svn/trunk | grep /exp.xml
```

So my question is whether it is possible to make any significant speedup to this query? One thing I am thinking of is maybe use some language, **preferably Perl**, to directly traverse the `http:/svn/trunk/` and process all the links, and stop traversing further down when it finds the first `exp.xml`.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be faster, I would try checking out the SVN project and then searching the files on disk. You could perform a search using "find" in the checked-out sandbox (where "." assumes you are in the top directory of your project):

```
find . -name 'exp.xml'
```

but, similar to your "grep" solution, I don't think it achieves your "stop searching further" criteria. If you want a Perl script to search for "exp.xml" but stop recursing if it finds a match, try this (takes top level directory as argument):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @dirs = $ARGV[0];

my @files;
DIR:
while (my $dir = shift @dirs) {
    opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die "Couldn't open dir $dir: $!";

    my @new_dirs;
    while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {
        # skip special directories (".", "..", and ".svn")
        next if $file =~ /^\./;

        # turn file into correct relative path
        $file = "$dir/$file";

        if (-d $file) {
            push @new_dirs, $file;
        }
        if ($file eq "$dir/exp.xml") {
            # if we matched, next outer loop so we don't recurse further
            push @files, $file;
            next DIR;
        }
    }
    # if we didn't match any files, we need to check sub-dirs
    push @dirs, @new_dirs;
}

print "$_\n" for @files;
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, but with the drawback that you have to check out the whole trunk. I was actually thinking if perl could read the html page `http://svn/trunk/` directly, because each svn page just consists of links to directories and files underneadth the current url, and so there isn't any significant difference to your solution. The only difference is traversing page links instead of folder "links". Do you have any idea how your script can be modified to do that, Muir?

Comment: By the way, I can verify that the solution works correctly, and finds about 300 files (in many thousand files), in less than a sec.

Comment: It could be modified to crawl the HTTP interface or the "svn ls" tree, but either of those will be very slow on a large repository, so that is why I skipped to my solution which requires first checking out the repository. If you still need to walk the web interface for whatever reason, look at LWP::UserAgent for fetching the pages (and then scrape them in Perl). Also consider Parallel::Forker for making your script multi-process (which would make the scraper much faster, but probably still pretty slow).

Answer (score 0):

Use `svn ls [URL]` or `svn ls -R [URL]` with your script to list the SVN repository starting at [URL]. See `svn ls --help` for more info.